# SQLite Syntax Error with Alter Command

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I tried to execute a SQLite `ALTER TABLE [...] RENAME TO [...]` function in PHP, but I keep running into an error: `Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: near "ALTER": syntax error in [file] on line 3`

The code seems simple to me, and I have tried to get around the error, but so far the problem has stumped two programmers.  I also get a similar error when trying to drop the table (`Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: near "EXISTS": syntax error in [file] on line 10`). Looking at the [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), the code seems to be ok:

```
<?php
    $db = sqlite_open("[database file]", 0666);
    sqlite_query($db, "ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO old_users");
    /* [...] */
    sqlite_query($db, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_users");
?>
```

Complete error page:

```
Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: near "ALTER": syntax error in [file] on line 3

Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: near "EXISTS": syntax error in [file] on line 10
```

Might anyone have any clue why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the changelogs, it seems that :

- `RENAME` has been added in [SQLite 3.1](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_1_0.html)
- and `IF EXISTS` has been added in [SQLite 3.3](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_3_0.html)

You are using [**SQLite**][3] functions -- which are for SQLite 2.

Try using the [**SQLite3**](https://www.php.net/sqlite3) API, which supports SQLite 3.

Comment: Thank you, I had false hopes that I could avoid learning OOP... _sigh_

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;; well, learning *(at least the basics of)* OOP is really something you should do, in 2011 ;-)

Comment: Yes, but as someone who is very busy, I tend to put off learning something I don't "need" to learn.

Comment: If you don't learn, one day, when your knowledge is outdated, you won't be busy anymore...

Comment: True, but I haven't seen any advantage to using OOP over functions, until now.  Also, I'm waiting for the summer, when I have time, to jump ahead in my learning.  (I did so last summer, going from WYSIWYG to basic PHP web design in about a month)

Comment: Summer... I would love having 1 or 2 month of holidays, and the free time that foes with it ^^ Anyway : have fun this summer ;-)

Comment: It's been a few years (and a few more of my questions that you've answered), but thanks for the final push to learn OOP that broke the camel's back.  I've fully converted to OOP now that I'm using Node.js/CoffeeScript.  Weird to look back and see the kickoff that convinced me to learn OOP.  You were right, it was stupid not to know OOP in 2011 :)  Oh, and I had a good summer :)